# Executing all test methods of a class while accessing only particular group of that class in TestNG

Tags: java, testng, testng-eclipse

I have following code snippet-

Class 1 :- DependencyOne.java

```
public class DependencyOne 
{
   @Test(groups = "xxx")
   public void parentTestMethodOne()
   {
        System.out.println("parent Test Method One");
   }
   @Test(groups = "vizac")
  public void parentTestMethodTwo()
  {
      System.out.println("parent Test Method Two");
  }
  @Test(groups = "xxx")
  public void parentTestMethodThree()
  {
      System.out.println("parent Test Method Three");
  } 
}
```

And The another class is

Class 2 :- DependencyTwo.java

```
public class DependencyTwo 
{

   @Test(dependsOnMethods = "testMethodThree")
   public void testMethodOne()
   {
      System.out.println("Test Method One");
   }
   @Test(dependsOnGroups = "xxx")
   public void testMethodTwo()
  {
     System.out.println("Test Method Two");
  }
    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "testMethodTwo")
    public void testMethodThree()
    {
       System.out.println("Test Method Three");
    }
}
```

When I'm executing the **DependencyTwo** it is giving following output -

parent Test Method One

parent Test Method Three

parent Test Method Two

Test Method Two

Test Method Three

Test Method One

And what I'm expecting is-

parent Test Method One

parent Test Method Three

Test Method Two

Test Method Three

Test Method One

Can any one please explain me why it is happening even I'm accessing only specified group's test methods of other class and Please suggest me how can I access only group specified test methods in other class.

[image]

Comment: Which testng are you using? How do you run your test? What is the relation between DependencyOne and DependencyTwo?

Comment: I'm using TestNG 6.9.10 libraries and executing the class directly (as a TestNg Test) where I have placed all methods e.g. DependencyTwo.but there are some common methods which are placed in another class e.g  DependencyOne .common methods categorized with group in DependencyOne class and I need to call all methods of that particular group before a test method in DependencyTwo class

Comment: Both classes are in same package

Comment: I still don't understand how you run your test. If you run all classes without a group filter then all methods will be run.

Comment: I have attached screenshot .I'm executing DependencyTwo  as a TestNG class

Comment: Here i have made group filter as expected to call all methods of xxx group from DependencyOne class as In only call DependencyTwo class

Comment: @NarendraRajput - I think you should maybe create a suite xml file that shows how you are intending to call your test classes. That way there's no guess work for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative so far I know

Just create one `testing.xml` file where you can manage your methods which you want to include/exclude-

Use following in your xml file -

```
<test name="MyTest">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <exclude name="vizac"/>
        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="com.flipkart.DependencyOne" />
        <class name="com.flipkart.DependencyTwo" />
    </classes>
</test>
```